# git svn clone - How to convert Subversion remotes to Git locals (Windows)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've attempted to follow the [official Git instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) on how to do a one-time, one-way migration of a project from Subversion to Git. I've attempted it a few times, with slightly different options, but I'm not getting the result that I expected.

The instructions suggest that the imported Subversion tags and branches should appear here in the newly created local Git repo after the import procedure is finished:

```
my-new-local-git-repo\.git\refs\remotes
```

But the Subversion tags/branches actually exist here:

```
my-new-local-git-repo\.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin
```

I suspect that's why the post-import cleanup instructions aren't working for me. I don't know if I've made a mistake in the command/options that I used to execute the import, if the instructions are out-of-date, or if I'm making a mistake elsewhere.

This is the command that I used to create this Subversion-to-Git migrated repo:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=users.txt http://svn/repo/root/MyProjectInSVN/ new-local-git-repo
```

Here are some screenshots of what the resulting local Git repo remote references look like:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Any suggestions on how I can convert these imported Subversion remote branches and tags into local Git branches and tag would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git uses *two* locations for storing refs (i.e. branches, tags, ...): First it stores each ref as an individual file below `.git/refs`. After a while and/or if to many refs have accumulated `git pack-refs` packs the current state into *one* file `.git/packed-refs`. `git pack-refs` is called by `git gc` which in turn is executed automatically by some git commands.

So it is not a bug that `.git/refs` does not contain your branches. The definitive command to get all refs is `git for-each-ref`.

`git svn` does store *additional* data in `git/svn` but not the refs per se.

If the post-processing did not work I assume that the patterns for the refs did not match. So compare the output of `git for-each-ref` with the strings in the commands: `refs/remotes/tags` and `refs/remotes`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your complete explanation of how the packed-refs works! I had used the `git for-each-ref` on previous migration attempts, but in those cases I made a mistake with some of the options I supplied to `git svn clone`, and the post-migration commands didn't work. My last migration attempt actually worked fine, but I hadn't run the post-migration commands because I was sidetracked by the missing `.git/refs`. Your explanation of `git for-each-ref` being the definitive command to iterate the refs was the missing piece of the puzzle!